# How to attach a 'TextMesh' property to a Cloned Object on Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm generating dynamic instances of class object on Unity 3D and are working good, but, when I'm trying to add an extra component `TextMesh`, I can't access to them to assign text.
The codes are:

**Bubble.cs**

```
public class Bubble : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 oldpos = Vector3.zero;
    public Team team = Team.Green;
    public Color teamColor;
    float blastRange = 4.0f;
    float moved = 0;
    public TextMesh nText = new TextMesh();

    void Start () {
        score = (Score)FindObjectOfType(typeof(Score));
        Game.game.bubbles.Add(this);

        nText.text = "123";
    }

}
```

But, when I'm trying to access to the `nText` property is always `null`.
Also, I can't link this `TextMesh` to a component defined in an scene because all the bubbles should have different values.

How, I can fix that?

The error is: `UnassignedReferenceException: The variable nText of Bubble has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the nText variable of the Bubble script in the inspector.`

Comment: Have you tried `gameObject.AddComponent<TextMesh>()` in your `Start` method

Comment: @GuruStron if you add your comment as an answer I going to mark it as the correct. With that works! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
nText = gameObject.AddComponent<TextMesh>()
```

in your `Start` method

Comment: That's true, I need a new dynamic component in my scene, that is the reason to get this error, now it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the new keyword for Unity components.

```
public TextMesh nText = new TextMesh();
```

should be

```
public TextMesh nText = null;

 void Start () {
        score = (Score)FindObjectOfType(typeof(Score));
        Game.game.bubbles.Add(this);
        nText = gameObject.AddComponent("TextMesh") as TextMesh;
        nText.text = "123";
    }
```